# How to sort a matrix based on two columns

Tags: matlab, datetime, sorting, date, matrix

I am trying to sort a cell matrix based on two columns using MATLAB:

```
ticker date price
msft 1/9/11 19.8
msft 1/8/11 18.7
csco 1/8/11 9.8
csco 1/9/11 10.0
```

I want to sort the matrix first by date then by ticker, so the result I want is:

```
ticker date price
csco 1/8/11 9.8
msft 1/8/11 18.7
csco 1/9/11 10.0
msft 1/9/11 19.8
```

Anyone knows how I can do that? THanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to understand how it works. Also, if you can decide on the best answer, accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 5):

I would convert the date column into the corresponding serial date number with [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html) and use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) with the required ordering to sort the data.

Here's some code ; assume `d` is your 4x3 cell array from the example you gave:

> ```
> d = 
>
> 'msft'    '1/9/11'    [19.8000]
> 'msft'    '1/8/11'    [18.7000]
> 'csco'    '1/8/11'    [ 9.8000]
> 'csco'    '1/9/11'    [     10]
> ```

- Convert the date column to numbers with [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html)

  ```
  d(:,2) = arrayfun(@(x){datenum(x)},d(:,2));
  ```
- Sort the matrix with [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html) (date first then ticker symbol)

  ```
  d = sortrows(d,[2 1]);
  ```
- Replace the date with a string with [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html).

  ```
  d(:,2) = arrayfun(@(x){datestr(x{1},'mm/dd/yy')},d(:,2));
  ```

Comment: elegant use of functional style.

Answer (score 1):

concatenate the two cell arrays into a single cell array of strings.  Sort the resultant cell array of strings and get the order of the indicies.  Use those indicies to sort the original cell arrays

```
a = {'1', '2', '2', '3'}
b = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'}
for i = 1:length(a)
   ab{i} = [a{i},b{i}]
end
[s,si] = sort(ab);
sorted_a = a(si);
sorted_b = b(si);
```

following Jacob's suggestion, if the date format you are using is not sortable alphabetically you can replace

```
   ab{i} = [a{i},b{i}]
```

with

```
   ab{i} = [num2str(datenum(a{i})),b{i}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar idea to [@Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681848/matlab-how-to-sort-a-matrix-based-on-two-columns/6681992#6681992)'s, here is a slightly easier solution:

```
%# your cell array
d = {
    'msft' '1/9/11' 19.8
    'msft' '1/8/11' 18.7
    'csco' '1/8/11'  9.8
    'csco' '1/9/11' 10.0
};

%# extract 2 columns, convert to serial date, sort, apply order to original data
[~,idx] = sortrows([datenum(d(:,2),'mm/dd/yy') cell2mat(d(:,3))], [1 2]);
d = d(idx,:)
```

The before:

```
d = 
    'msft'    '1/9/11'    [19.8]
    'msft'    '1/8/11'    [18.7]
    'csco'    '1/8/11'    [ 9.8]
    'csco'    '1/9/11'    [  10]
```

The after:

```
d = 
    'csco'    '1/8/11'    [ 9.8]
    'msft'    '1/8/11'    [18.7]
    'csco'    '1/9/11'    [  10]
    'msft'    '1/9/11'    [19.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[tblB,index] = sortrows(tblA,{'Height','Weight'},{'ascend','descend'})
```

for your specific case:

```
ticker date price
msft 1/9/11 19.8
msft 1/8/11 18.7
csco 1/8/11 9.8
csco 1/9/11 10.0
```

```
[tblB,index] = sortrows(tblA,{'date','price'},{'ascend','descend'})
```