# How to specify ROIs from left to right in MAtlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, object-detection, roi

I'm a fresher to Matlab. I'm working on vision.CascadeObjectDetector on Mat-lab and is used twice to find-out two different objects(separately trained), say E and K from a video. bbox and bbox2 are respective ROIs. part of code is given below

```
while ~isDone(videoFileReader)
videoFrame=step(videoFileReader);
bbox=step(letterDetector_E,videoFrame);
bbox2=step(letterDetector_K,videoFrame);
C = vertcat(bbox,bbox2); 
videoOut=insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame, 'rectangle', C, 'E&K');
step(videoPlayer, videoOut);
end
```

I want to take each ROI(both bbox and bbox2 considering together) one by one from left two right, top to bottom like reading a page. how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the format of `bbox` here, but assuming it is a vector `bbox = [xUpperLeft, yUpperLeft, width, height]`, you simply need to sort by two columns in succession. For this you can use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
sortrows(C, [1 2]);
```

This sorts the rows of `C` first by `xUpperLeft` (the first column), and then by `yUpperLeft` (the second column). See also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681848/how-to-sort-a-matrix-based-on-two-columns).

Comment: ya. bbox format is same as u assume...  
thanks... let me check whether it works for my project :-)